# Unity2D Why is the spawner not showing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Canvas Setting:

[image]

Background Image Setting:

[image]

Spawner Setting:

[image]

Gameplay Screen:

[image]

Note: (Canvas Scaler > Screen Match Mode to Expand) The spawner does not appear after making this setting. Spawner staying behind the background picture

Spawner Script

```
    public GameObject skullPrefab;
    public GameObject goldPrefab;

    private float minX = -1.5f;
    private float MaxX = 1.5f;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBombs());
        StartCoroutine(SpawnGolds());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnBombs()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.2f, 0.5f));

        Instantiate(skullPrefab, new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, MaxX), transform.position.y), Quaternion.identity);

        StartCoroutine(SpawnBombs());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnGolds()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.7f, 1f));

        Instantiate(goldPrefab, new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, MaxX), transform.position.y), Quaternion.identity); 

        StartCoroutine(SpawnGolds());
    }
}
```

Comment: does your spawner spawns those gold in world space or in canvas ?

Comment: probably world space but I want it to be on Background it lags behind spawner

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your spawner spawns those golds in world space and since your canvas is a screen space -
overlay canvas, it will always be on the foreground and worldspace objects will be behind it.

1. If your gold objects are 2d then try spawning them inside your canvas and make sure they are in front.
2. If your gold objects are 3d Change your canvas to screen space - camera and then your rendering will be depending on which object is closer to camera so you can adjust it as you want. (I would prefer the first solution if possible)
3. Try looking into render textures and how they work.